# React-Redux: Assigning a modified array to a property in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a React application and I am using Redux to store the state. I have the following the code:

menu.actions.js:

```
import { apiUrl, apiConfig } from '../../util/api';
import { ADD_CATEGORY, GET_MENU } from './menu.types';

export const getMenu = () => async dispatch => {
    const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/menu`);
    if (response.ok) {
        const menuData = await response.json();
        dispatch({ type: GET_MENU, payload: menuData })
    }
}

export const addCategory = category => async dispatch => {
    const options = {
        ...apiConfig(),
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(category)
    };
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl + '/category/', options)
    let data = await response.json()
    if (response.ok) {
        dispatch({ type: ADD_CATEGORY, payload: { ...data } })
    } else {
        alert(data.error)
    }
}
```

menu.reducer.js:

```
import { ADD_CATEGORY, GET_MENU } from './menu.types';

const INITIAL_STATE = []

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_MENU:
            return [...action.payload];
        case ADD_CATEGORY:
            return [ ...state, { ...action.payload, menuItem: [] } ]
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In the above Reducer, the initial state is an empty array. Dispatching the GET_MENU action, changes the initial state so that it contains an array of menu items instead.

The array that is fetched in the GET_MENU action is of the following:

[image]

I have modified the code in the Reducer function so that the initial state is now the following:

menu.reducernew.js:

```
import { ADD_CATEGORY, GET_MENU } from './menu.types';

    const INITIAL_STATE = {
        menuArray: [],
        isSending: false
    };

    export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case GET_MENU:
                return {
                ...state,
                menuArray: action.payload
            };
            case ADD_CATEGORY:
                return {
                ...state,
                menuArray: [ ...menuArray, { ...action.payload, menuItem: [] } ]
            };

            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
```

For the case `ADD_CATEGORY` in the Reducer, I am not sure what the correct syntax is for reassigning the menuArray property in the state to the modified array. I want the array to have the new object that is fetched within the `addCategory` action creator added to it.

When I run my application, I am getting the following error:

[image]

I am not sure why I am getting this error or how to resolve it. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `menuArray: [ ...menuArray, { ...action.payload, menuItem: [] }` menuArray variable is not defined which you are trying to spread. Use `state.menuArray` to access current `menuArray`.

Change:

`menuArray: [ ...menuArray, { ...action.payload, menuItem: [] }`

To:

`menuArray: [ ...state.menuArray, { ...action.payload, menuItem: [] }`

```
case ADD_CATEGORY:
     return {
          ...state,
        menuArray: [ ...state.menuArray, { ...action.payload, menuItem: [] } ]
};
```